# iCloud Drive: Cannot download files?

Tags: icloud

Not sure if this is an implementation bug or iCloud clogged up.

On one mac I have uploaded a folder. I know upload is finished because when I log into icloud.com I can see the files and download them. Yet on another mac the files show like this:

[image: icloud files]

They cannot be opened, dragged or downloaded. The Get Info shows as if the file is on the hard drive with all the correct meta.

Has anyone come across this, or know of a solution?

As a side note, some older files that I uploaded a week ago show correctly now. Is it really taking this long to sync?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's just slow.

After a few hour some of the items are now usable. If you Get Info on the iCloud Drive folder and leave it for a short while you will see the size slowly increase as the downloads progress.

I guess this is a side effect of pushing all files to all macs and having every man and his dog uploading stuff to iCloud right now.

Comment: More likely it tries to download at slower speeds to avoid overwhelming your connection.