# iCloud will not download onto IMac

Tags: macos, icloud

I have several Apple devices and all are connected to the iCloud. My iMac however will not download any files from the cloud, it is an empty file! I have done the following.

- Signed out and back into my iCloud account.
- Restarted.
- unchecked the sync button and rechecked.

What can I do?

Comment: Hi, welcome! Uncheck optimise storage in iCloud options in System Preferences. Check internet connection, though sign out and in leaves no doubt, but still. Firewall? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157862/icloud-drive-cannot-download-files?rq=1 <- this says that it's just slow. Maybe other processes are hogging bandwidth. Check for that in Activity Monitor. What is OS version btw?

Comment: Internet is working well but I can't see optimize storage anywhere /Users/paulmiller/Dropbox/Screenshots/Screenshot 2019-08-19 09.51.50.png

Comment: You can use https://imgur.com for. screenshots. Go to system Preferences-> iCloud -> iCloud Drive options -> bottom is optimisation. Did you  see activity monitor -> network tab for any heavy usage? Also what is your icloud storage? More data will take more time to download.

Comment: Mine does not have the option to optimize storage on this IMac. My macBook Pro does.